# Get icon main color and select predefined color from list

Tags: c#, image, colors, icons, microsoft-metro

I have the problem, that i need to figure out the main color of an icon, and selected the "nearest" color from a list in c#.

At first i have a list with colors, for example:

1. R: 176, G: 30, B: 0
2. R: 114, G: 0, B: 172
3. R: 25, G: 153, B: 0
4. R: 255, G: 183, B: 0
5. ...

Than i have a list of icons:

1. New Document
2. Save
3. Folder/Directory
4. ...

Now i want to get the main color in every icon and than get the color, which is as similar as possible to one of the predefined list.

My first solution was, to get the RGB value from every icon pixel and then devide through the amout of pixels, but then i only get some brown and gray colors.

Does any one has a solution for this problem?

Thank you very much!

Comment: How do you define `main color` ?

Comment: I'd guess you're getting strange colors because you're taking averages of each color component separately. Sounds good in theory, but it can throw off your answer if you have many different colors in your image. Say your icon is 33% of each 255 R, 255 G, and 255 B... Your "color" would be about 85% of each (aka dark gray). As far as averaging goes, this isn't *wrong* necessarily.

Answer (score 1):

I have an idea for you (assuming I understand your issue correctly, correct me if I do not). Let me start by re-stating my comment on your post:

> I'd guess you're getting strange colors because you're taking averages of each color component separately. Sounds good in theory, but it can throw off your answer if you have many different colors in your image. Say your icon is 33% of each 255 R, 255 G, and 255 B... Your "color" would be about 85% of each (aka dark gray). As far as averaging goes, this isn't wrong necessarily.

So here's my proposed technique (again, assuming I understand that you're after the most common color, not average):
What you could do, is store (in whichever structure you deem appropriate) which color on your list is "closest" to each pixel using some margin of error (comparing the RBG values). Then, after all pixels have been accounted for and their "votes" applied to your data structure, see which color on the list has most pixels associated to that color. Then that color is the "winner".

Comment: As Nicholas Ellingson's answer suggests, a dictionary would be a simple and easy way to do this. But as longs as it scales to how many colors you're checking against, any structure should be fine.

Comment: Because this is a one time process, the time it needs is not very important. Thank you for your idea, i will try it and post some results tomorrow. Thank you both!

Answer (score 1):

What you're getting is the average color - which would be a brown gray color for most images. What it sounds like you want is the most "common" color - try Making a `Dictionary<color, int>` and as you loop through each pixel in the image, check if the color is in the dictionary with some margin of error (10% maybe?) and if it is, then you increment that value in the dictionary, if not then you add it to the dictionary.